# How to use querySelector in Tabulator JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabulator

I am trying TabulatorJS 5.2. in order to build tables.

I am facing issue i dont know why it exists. but after building the table i am trying to querySelect it but no result comes back. if i select the main table i can see the table. how can i get the elements of the table after building it.

Here I am trying to console.log the table using the table id

```
console.log( document.querySelector('#example-table') )
```

the console result :-
[image]

so apparently i can get the main table query.

also if i used jquery..

```
console.log( $('#example-table') )
```

[image]

And i can list the childs

[image]

But if i tried to query on the the inside elements like headers,
i got no result !

```
console.log( $('.tabulator-header') )
```

I am new to this. so what i am missing here ?

[image]

Comment: Try `const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('#example-table > div')` then `console.log(nodeList[0])` should get you `div.tabulator-header`

Comment: Tabulator uses a virtual DOM, it is not advisable to try and manipulate DOM elements from outside the table as they can be replaced at any time by the virtual DOM, if you could explain what you are trying to achieve by doing this, maybe we could recommend a more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the tabulator table to be built before trying to query its elements.  Tabulator has a `tableBuilt` event you can use for this purpose to make sure the table is available in the DOM before interacting with it.  Take the following example. First `console.log` will give you `null`.  The second one inside `tableBuilt` event will give you the result you want.

```js
let tableData = [
  {id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12"},
  {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1"},
]

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data:tableData, //set initial table data
  columns:[
    {title:"Name", field:"name"},
    {title:"Age", field:"age"}
  ]
})

console.log(document.querySelector('.tabulator-header'))

table.on("tableBuilt", () => {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.tabulator-header'))
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```